# Basic Kohana ORM find records

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I want to fetch some rows from my databases using the default ORM that Kohana 3 has, but I'm not getting what I want :-)

```
In my Controller:

$comptes = ORM::factory('compte');
#$comptes->where('empresa_id', '=', 2)->find_all();
$comptes->find_all();
```

This Query returns 169411 rows in my SQL, but here returns nothing. Of course I can limit using where, limit, or whatever, but I'm experimenting the basics with Kohana.

```
This returns 1
$result = count($comptes);



In my model view:
<?php var_dump($comptes)?>

produces this:
object(Model_Compte)#16 (34) { ["_has_one":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_belongs_to":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_has_many":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_load_with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_validation":protected]=> NULL ["_object":protected]=> array(14) { ["id"]=> NULL ["empresa_id"]=> NULL ["codi_compte"]=> NULL ["compte"]=> NULL ["tipus"]=> NULL ["saldo_deure"]=> NULL ["saldo_haver"]=> NULL ["saldo"]=> NULL ["nivell"]=> NULL ["ultim_moviment"]=> NULL ["client_id"]=> NULL...
```

So this is the model, but how I can get the fetched data?

Also in my view:

```
foreach ($comptes as $row)
{
 echo "<p>$row->codi_compte</p>";
}
?>
```

But I don't get nothing ...

thanks!

### EDIT

This doesn't work:

```
$comptes = ORM::factory('compte');
$comptes->find_all();
```

But this works
     $comptes = ORM::factory('compte')->find_all();

Why?

And this doesn't work:

```
$comptes = ORM::factory('compte');
$comptes->where('empresa_id', '=', 2)->find_all();
```

But again, this works:

```
$comptes = ORM::factory('compte')->where('empresa_id', '=', 2)->find_all();
```

This multi-lines examples are from [Kohana Web](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/orm/examples/simple)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax to get all the rows would be:

```
$comptes = ORM::factory('compte')->find_all();
```

Then to check if something has been loaded use `$comptes->loaded()` (not `count($comptes)`).

**Edit:**

To get rows using a `where` statement, you would write:

```
$rows = ORM::factory('compte')->where('empresa_id', '=', 2)->find_all();
```

Comment: Ok, if I use your syntax I can fetch all rows, if I split into two lines, it doesn't work, strange for me. Also, if I want to fetch using'where', I'm having the same problem as before, no rows, but sure there are rows with this 'where'.

Comment: Yes, but why the multiline doesn't work, when the examples/docs from Kohana web say yes ?

Comment: hmm... not sure why the examples are like that. Kohana's doc is sometime inaccurate or outdated, so maybe it used to work like that but doesn't anymore. In fact, if you look at this page http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/using you'll see the same syntax I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: ok, I see, my docs are from kohana3.0 and yours are from 3.2, this is a problem, few documentation and most of them old or outdated, I came from RoR and there things are easier, at least at the begining ;-). thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
$comptes = ORM::factory('compte');
$comptes->find_all();
```

This doesnt work because you didn't assign find_all() result in a variables.
You should write :

```
$comptes = ORM::factory('compte');
$rows = $comptes->find_all();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to break it down into multiple lines for readability's sake, this is the simplest method IMO...

**Example:**

```
$comptes = ORM::factory('compte')
    ->where('empresa_id', '=', 2)
    ->find_all();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$comptes = ORM::factory('compte');
$comptes->find_all();
```

This doesn't work because you use semicolon.
semicolon means end of statement.

It will work fine if you erase semicolon like this:

```
$comptes = ORM::factory('compte')
->find_all();
```

Or make it as 1 line only:

```
$comptes = ORM::factory('compte')->find_all();
```